# Delete na tabela através de Shell Script

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, pl-sql

Eu estou tentando fazer um delete de todas as linhas de uma tabela através de Shell Script.
O banco de dados é oracle. O banco por algum motivo não me deixa fazer truncate e o delete simplesmente não deleta, sem apresentar qualquer erro. Eu realmente não sei o porquê disso, ao tentar fazer tais operações através do PL/SQL Developer, eu consigo normalmente, porém através do Linux eu não consigo.

Código que estou usando:

```
    sqlplus -s usuario/senha <<EOF 
    delete from table;
    exit;
    EOF
```

Comment: nao sou especialista no oracle mas não teria que usar `commit;` após o `delete` e antes do `exit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eu descobri que o meu problema era que o banco estava me impedindo de executar tal ação. Eu conseguia ver e inserir, porém excluir não era possível porque a tabela estava 'bloqueada'. Após uma conversa com um DBA 'liberamos' a tabela e conseguimos executar o delete. Obrigada pela ajuda. O código permaneceu o mesmo.